# Scala Java interop typechecking

Tags: scala, typechecking

I am unable to fix these typechecking errors in Scala:

```
package junk

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job

object Sample {
  val conf: Configuration = new Configuration()
  val job: Job = new Job(conf, "sample Hadoop MapReduce program");

  job.setInputFormatClass(classOf[TextInputFormat])
  job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TextOutputFormat])
  job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TextOutputFormat[Text, IntWritable]])
}
```

The error messages are

```
Sample.scala:14: error: type mismatch;
found   : java.lang.Class[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat](classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat])
required: java.lang.Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat]
 job.setInputFormatClass(classOf[TextInputFormat])
                                ^
Sample.scala:15: error: class TextOutputFormat takes type parameters
 job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TextOutputFormat])
                                  ^
Sample.scala:16: error: type mismatch;
found   : java.lang.Class[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable]](classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat])
required: java.lang.Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputFormat]
 job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TextOutputFormat[Text, IntWritable]])
```

Note that I have tried to setOutputFormatClass in two different ways and both fail.

I am trying to write Hadoop WordCount: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount in Scala. The equivalent lines in Java are

```
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

API docs for Job: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892359/scala-type-mismatch-error-should-be-inherited.  The issue may be a bug with Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Scala 2.9.1 (not Scala 2.9.0 -- see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4603), this also works:

```
job.setInputFormatClass(classOf[TextInputFormat])
```

Answer (score 4):

See [Programming In Scala, Existential Types](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combining-scala-and-java.html#29.3).

```
val textInputFormatClass = classOf[TextInputFormat].
     asInstanceOf[Class[T] forSome {type T <: InputFormat[String, String]}]

job.setInputFormatClass(textInputFormatClass)
```

Substitute the types that you are using for `[String, String]`

```
scala> val textInputFormatClass = classOf[TextInputFormat].asInstanceOf[Class[T] forSome {type T <: InputFormat[String, String]}]
textInputFormatClass: java.lang.Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[String,String]] = class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

scala> val job = new Job
job: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job = org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job@4a205144

scala> job.setInputFormatClass(textInputFormatClass)

scala>
```

Comment: Definitely on the right track here.  Unfortunately the first line gives the error message "error: class InputFormat takes type parameters" and if I add type or wildcard parameters to InputFormat, then the second line doesn't compile because the signature is different.

Comment: Ok - so I downloaded Hadoop now :)  Updated answer.

Comment: Thx for going to all the trouble.  I had tried that, and received following error in both Scala 2.9.0 compiler and interpreter: Error found   : java.lang.Class[T] where type T <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[String,String]
 required: java.lang.Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat]

Comment: This code is broken in 2.9.0 and fixed as of 2.9.1: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4603