# scala type mismatch error should be inherited

Tags: scala, hadoop, type-mismatch

I've been working on getting a hadoop / scala bridge working on my machine and when I'm setting up the job I am getting the following error from the compiler.

```
[error]  found   : java.lang.Class[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat (classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat])
[error]  required: java.lang.Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputFormat]
[error]     conf setInputFormat classOf[TextInputFormat]
```

I'm not sure how to proceed here given that TextInputFormat does in fact implement InputFormat.

(See: http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextInputFormat.html)

Is there a possibility that this isn't working b/c of a raw type issue where TextInputFormat implements InputFormat with a specific set of parameters?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

EDIT: also, for the offending line of code, conf is a JobConf, is one of these  http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html

Comment: This works in the REPL: `class A; class B extends A; val cls: Class[_ <: A]= classOf[B]` so you'll have to give us more context here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a known bug in Java-Scala interop with raw types, Issue [SI 4603](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4603), which is now [fixed in trunk](https://codereview.scala-lang.org/fisheye/changelog/scala-svn?cs=25394). Could you try your code with a Scala [nightly build](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/212/distributions) and see if the issue is resolved?

See also: [How does one implement a Hadoop Mapper in Scala 2.9.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028221/how-does-one-implement-a-hadoop-mapper-in-scala-2-9-0)

Comment: I changed the error to include the actual offending line of code, which does include classOf[TextInputFormat]